# Bounded holomorphic function attaching supremum and infimum through vertical lines

Tags: complex-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Let $H := \{z \in \mathbb{C}: Re(z) > 0\}$ be the open right half-plane. I would like to construct a holomorphic function $f:H\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that $|f|$ is bounded and bounded away from zero in $H$, and such that there exist $x_1, x_2 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $$\sup\limits_{z\in H} |f(z)| = \lim\limits_{t\rightarrow+\infty} |f(x_1+it)|$$ $$\inf\limits_{z\in H} |f(z)|= \lim\limits_{t\rightarrow+\infty} |f(x_2-it)|.$$ That is, the supremum and the infimum of $|f|$ is attached by taking limits in two vertical lines, the first one with increasing imaginary part and the second one with decreasing imaginary part.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you very much in advance!!

Comment: What is the motivation for this?

Comment: It's just a curiosity, I thought about this example but I'm not able to provide such a construction... I would like to know if such a holomorphic function can be defined

Comment: by the usual convexity theorems ($\log M_x$ is convex where $M_x$ is the vertical line supremum of $|f|$ and same for $\log m_x$ when the function has no zeroes and $m_x$ is the infimum) the requirement above implies that $\sup\limits_{z\in H} |f(z)| = \lim\limits_{t\rightarrow+\infty} |f(x+it)|$ for all $x>0$ and same for the infimum; now this doesn;t preclude the existence of such an $f$ - for example $e^{\frac{1/\Gamma (z+A)-C}{ 1/\Gamma (z+A)+C}}$ works for the supremum which is $e$ (at both $|t| \to \infty$) for some $A,C >0$ and probably one can get cleverer and get the infimum